# Can the hypergeometric function be extended analytically to the complex plane in the interval [1,$\infty$ )?

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

Just a thought. The hypergeometric function, which can be written as:

$$F(a,b,c \space;z) = \frac{\Gamma (c)}{\Gamma (b) \Gamma (c-b)}\int_0^1t^{b-1}(1-t)^{c-b-1}(1-zt)^{-a}dt$$

is obviously continuous on the unit disc. I was wondering if it could be extended to the positive real line?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_integral

Comment: So it can be? Sorry, wikipedia has a way of over-complicating an idea

Comment: The contour integration representation allows you to analytically continue the hypergeometric function to the entire complex plane. I'll link to a paper which unfortunately doesn't include a picture of the contour. I have another paper on my computer that I'll try to find on the internet. http://aw.twi.tudelft.nl/~koekoek/documents/wi4006/barnes.pdf‎

Comment: The paper was EXACTLY what I needed to solve this :)
Thank you!

Comment: But definitely we should avoid $(1, \infty)$. (Even this condition is explicitly mentioned in the paper in the form $|\arg(-z)|<\pi$.) An easy way of checking the unavoidability of branch cut is to plug $(b, c) = (1, 2)$ and find an exact formula. (Of course, you may choose different branch cut that does not intersect $(1, \infty)$ but at least there is no hope of getting a meromorphic function on $\Bbb{C}$ for general parameters.)

Answer (score 1):

> The contour integration representation ([Barnes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_integral)) allows one to analytically continue the hypergeometric function to the entire complex plane. 
>   See [Roelof Koekoek](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/onderw1314/specfunc_en.html)'s lecture supplement [Barnes integral representation](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/wi4006/barnes.pdf).  -- [Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755063/can-the-hypergeometric-function-be-extended-analytically-to-the-complex-plane-in#comment1572178_755063)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Transformation formulae $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)=(1-z)^{-b}{}_2F_1\left(b,c-a;c;\dfrac{z}{z-1}\right)$ or $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)=(1-z)^{-a}{}_2F_1\left(a,c-b;c;\dfrac{z}{z-1}\right)$ in e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Transformation_formulas